# Radius of convergence of $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\ln(1+\frac{1}{k})}{k}x^k$, I don't understand the solution

Tags: sequences-and-series

The exercise is to calculate the radius of convergence of  $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\ln(1+\frac{1}{k})}{k}x^k$. 
The solution of the book is the following:

> Because of $\frac{1}{1+k}=\frac{\frac{1}{k}}{1+\frac{1}{k}}\leq \ln(1+\frac{1}{k})\leq\frac{1}{k}$ then $ \sqrt[k]{|a_k|}\rightarrow1$

I'm only sure that it uses the root test to calculate the radius, but I don't know how is it exactly used in this case. I also know that $(1+\frac{1}{k})^k$ converges to $e$ but again I don't understand how is this fact used.

Comment: you could also say that $\ln (1+1/k) \sim 1/k$ so $\sqrt[k]{\ln (1+1/k) }\to 1/\sqrt[k]{k} =  1/e^{(\ln k)/k} \to 1$

Comment: Thanks for answering! Is it allowed? I mean mathematically, can we approximate a function and say that the limit of the approximation is the limit of the function?

Comment: that's a good start : write it down and see it if is allowed. $f(x) \sim g(x)$ here means that $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) / g(x) = 1$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: For large $k,\ln (1+1/k)\approx 1/k.$ Ask yourself: What is the radius of convergence for $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}x^k/k^2?$

Answer (score 0):

It is known that for all $k\geq 1$, it holds that
$$
\left( {1 + \frac{1}{k}} \right)^k  < e < \left( {1 + \frac{1}{k}} \right)^{k + 1} .
$$
Taking logarithms yields
$$
k\log \left( {1 + \frac{1}{k}} \right) < 1 < (k + 1)\log \left( {1 + \frac{1}{k}} \right),
$$
i.e.,
$$
\frac{1}{{k + 1}} < \log \left( {1 + \frac{1}{k}} \right) < \frac{1}{k}.
$$
Thus,
$$
\sqrt[k]{{\frac{1}{{k(k + 1)}}}} \le \sqrt[k]{{\left| {a_k } \right|}} \le \sqrt[k]{{\frac{1}{{k^2 }}}}.
$$
Hence, by the squeeze theorem, $\sqrt[k]{{\left| {a_k } \right|}} \to 1$. This implies, by the Cauchy--Hadamard theorem, that the radius of convergence is $1$.